# simple for us to go out -- what does that mean?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [Lecture 3 | Programming Paradigms (Stanford)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H4MQXBF6FN4#t=47m) (It's a Youtube video,  So just click the link and it will automatically take you to the exact moment he says it.  I have put in a time stamp for you there.)

Example:

> Let me just write a function I know you've seen before and **it's actually charmingly simple for us to go out** because this is all very difficult compared to what I'm about to write.

Specifically, I don't understand what **for us to go out** means.

Comment: This is new to me, but I'm guessing he meant "It's very simple to go on with" ?

Comment: I've not heard that phrase before.  Mind you, I've only been speaking English for 42 years, so I've not heard everything. :)  It sounds like a throwaway phrase, without any great meaning.  I'd not worry about it, if I were you.  If you're listening to programming paradigm talks from Stanford, you have bigger things to deal with!

Comment: Are you asking for the construction *for + object + infinitive*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He kind of mumbles at that point, but it may be that he's saying

> It's charmingly simple for us to go on

The phrase "to go on" would mean "to preceed with".

I was hoping the closed captions would help, but those look like they were generated by speech recognition software; it's horribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The guy stumbles a lot in his pronunciation (listen to ~46:26 *eg*). It could be that he intends to say "...go on", as Gabriel suggests, and that his tongue and his brain don't cooperate, perhaps because of other things or words (maybe *wri**te***, which is both a word he says 2+ times and action he is thinking he has to perform); or he means "...go out", in which case I've no idea what he means, unless he wants this topic to be the one that class "goes out" (concludes) with.